# Firefox deleted recent bookmarks – how to prevent this?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, bookmarks

When I was getting ready to close Firefox, I made bookmarks of some pages I intended to revisit by dragging them to the bookmarks bar. They appeared correctly, and in one instance I fixed up a link in the bookmark editing dialogue box so it included a time code, so I could resume at a specific point in a video. The bookmarks appeared, with their site icons, on the bookmarks bar, so I'm absolutely certain the bookmarks were made correctly. I proceeded, closing tabs, making bookmarks as necessary in the process, until I close the last tab and Firefox was closed.

But when I reopened Firefox later all those bookmarks were gone! Older bookmarks, from the day before yesterday and earlier, are still there, but the ones I specifically made to revisit now are all gone. I have tried the usual avenues of restoring bookmarks, but to no avail. Apparently the most recent backup of my bookmarks (in the bookmarkbackups folder) was made four days ago.

So my question is, why did this happen and how do I prevent it happening in the future? And any tips perhaps for coping?

P.S. I'm asking the question here because Mozilla has long ago stopped listening to normal users like me. I'd switch to a better browser, but I'm not convinced the competition is any better in this regard, which is probably why Mozilla is the way it is.

Comment: I don't know the answer I'm afraid, but what happens if you repeat this action? Does the same thing happen every time you try it, or was this a one off?

Comment: I closed the browser using my normal browser closing routine, but this is the first time Firefox deleted bookmarks like this. But you raise a good point... Firefox might delete my bookmarks again... But that means that I cannot easily repeat it now, because I'll have to write stuff down and figure out how to make backups and I haven't got the time. Maybe in the evening.

Comment: @Anonymous Please tell us which version of Firefox you are using.

Comment: I had time to test and it didn't happen again. But this was the first time it happened, so that was to be expected. Version is 89.0.2 and release notes of the last few versions mention nothing about a horrible bookmarks bug being fixed.

Comment: So you're asking us why happened something that you can't repeat, for a browser that you don't believe in its developers, that actually you don't believe in any developer of any browser. So why bother posting this question?

Comment: For the same reason everyone else asks questions, in hope of an answer or advice. Specifically, I was hoping that someone, maybe someone who had experienced this before for example, might be able to tell me why this happened, how to prevent it or perhaps how to try to cope, as I clearly wrote in the question. The real question should be why you bothered posting that comment. If you cannot answer then just don't. And if nobody can then that's just the way it is.